# How to add odometry into hector slam?

Tags: slam, navigation, odometry, hector-slam, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, we are using [hector slam](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam) for builiding 2D map with [rpliar laser](http://wiki.ros.org/rplidar). To solve the problem that false mapping in environmets similiar to long corridor, we want to add odometry into hector slam.

We read the source code of [hector_mapping](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam/tree/catkin/hector_mapping). We think that we can achieve our goal by setting the parameter "[p_use_tf_pose_start_estimate_](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam/blob/catkin/hector_mapping/src/HectorMappingRos.cpp#L268)" to be true.

In this way, the mapping process uses the odometry information stored in tf tree. The parameter "p_use_tf_pose_start_estimated_" may not be set to be true in the beginning. When the robot is going to walk througth a corridor, "p_use_tf_pose_start_estimated_" is set to be true.

However, in our tests, whenever the "p_use_tf_pose_start_estimate_" is set to be true, it always output following error

```
 [ERROR] [1501720267.512793847]: Transform from map to base_link failed with Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 84.940000000 but the latest data is at time 84.740000000, when looking up transform from frame [base_link] to frame [map]
```

So solve this error, we launched move_base as [this link](http://answers.ros.org/question/99736/navigate-using-hector_slam/) suggests. But it didn't work.

So we have two questions
1, How to solve above error? Why is it difficult for reading transforms from tf tree in hector slam?

2, What are other ways for adding odometry information into hector slam?

Looking for any valuable advices! Many thanks!
Best Regards!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267946/how-to-add-odometry-into-hector-slam?/) by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 279 on 2017-08-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2017-08-03**:
who is providing the base_link -> map transform? if it is AMCL, can you post the launch/config file, please?

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2017-08-03**:
It is an online mapping and navigation, so we don't use AMCL. Hector slam provides the base_link-> map transform. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !

I'm not sure this can help but I'm using RTABMap to build a map and in order to do that, I have to launch hector_mapping thanks to this [modified launch file](https://zero.crans.org/?dc90f953b0464065#ts0Xjnfo2ai8BE4iKBZfBckCh0Alg0fBqjIFzHp2OhA=), so that **hector_mapping provides the odometry** needed by RTABMap, and my first test indicated it was working (odometry showed nicely in RVIZ, and behaved as expected).

During the test, I got the following tf tree thanks to

> view_frames

[image: tf tree]

[Here](https://zero.crans.org/?886ca5790f5349b2#SoCHF2Bw0jV+0dMGIORGKcDF7WuKkgTOcpJ5zRdmay8=) is the command line RTABMap log, which includes hector_mapping messages.

The rtabmap tutorial I used to set this up is [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros/Tutorials/SetupOnYourRobot#Kinect_.2B-_2D_laser) if you want to check the source of the launch file.

The use of hector_mapping to generate odometry in order to obtain a map thanks to RTABMap is also discussed [here](http://official-rtab-map-forum.67519.x6.nabble.com/RGBD-Lidar-for-SLAM-and-autonomous-navigation-td3511.html) and [here](http://official-rtab-map-forum.67519.x6.nabble.com/RGB-D-Mapping-with-Laser-scanner-td25.html) on RTABMap dedicated forum (posts on how to adapt the launch file).

Hope this helped you !

---

Originally posted by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) with karma: 127 on 2017-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2017-08-03**:
Thank you! It is a useful experience for us. It seems that another running package would influences the running time of data processing.  We can't use camera, we will consider your advice when it is necessary.

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2017-08-04**:
@Blupon I found the parameter settings of hector mapping in your project, the parameter "p_use_tf_pose_start_estimate_" is not involved. Have you tried by setting it to be true and run your project again? Thanks!

**Comment by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) on 2017-08-08**:
I see that parameter in my logs but I don't see it described on hector_mapping [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_mapping), nor explained by google. Why do you wish to change it ? RTABMap's creator let it that way when using hector_mapping's odometry, I guess he had a good reason to ^^

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2017-08-08**:
We want the hector_mapping to build map with odometry information. The odometry information from the robot's wheel encoder. We don't want to use the odom data produced by the scan matching of hector_mapping.

**Comment by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) on 2017-08-08**:
Right ! it seems I misunderstood your aim & forgot to read your question update, my bad. How do you change the parameter ? Can you do it at launch ?

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2017-08-08**:
The odom data has been fused into tf tree. We think the keypoint is the paramter "p_use_tf_pose_start_estimate_". If this paramter is set to be true, the odom information from tf data can be  used for estimate the pose of robot. However, as our question above mentioned, it failed.We don't know why

**Comment by [Blupon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27530/blupon/) on 2017-08-08**:
my question was: how do you set it to true ? :-)

**Comment by [scopus](https://answers.ros.org/users/8561/scopus/) on 2017-08-08**:
In your launch file, add  `<param name="use_tf_pose_start_estimate" value="true"/>`
Maybe this parameter should be used with parameter  **p_map_with_known_poses_** , so you also can try by adding  `<param name="map_with_known_poses" value="true"/>`. The default value of these two paramters are false.